# php turn files in directories to href links

Tags: php, html, download, directory

I am using the following code to list directory/subdirectory files:

```
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <?php
    function listFolderFiles($dir)
    {
        $ffs = scandir($dir);
        echo '<ol>';
        foreach($ffs as $ff)
        {
            if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..')
            {
                echo '<li>'.$ff;
                if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff))
                {
                    listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
                }
                echo '</li>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ol>';
    }
    listFolderFiles('exportReports');
   ?>
   </div>
   </div>
```

What I need to do now is turn all the files inside each directory into href links that a user can click and download.

When I added 'a' tags in the echo statement with the opening 'li' tag, it turned all the directories and files into links.  I do not want this.  The actual file inside each directory needs to be a link.

The files are both .txt files as well as .html files.

Please help.

Comment: Sounds like you just didn't close your `<a>` tag which would enclose everything after it in the same `<a>` tag. `echo "<li><a href='$dir/$ff'>$ff</a>";`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, I was sure to close the 'a' tag exactly like how you have it listed above.  However, it still made all the directories and files hyperlinks.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Then you need to explain more what you are talking about. You say you "it turned all the directories and file into links" but you don't want that, you want the "file file inside each directory to be a link". Isn't that the same thing? You want the links, but you don't want the link? Perhaps an example of your desired output.

Comment: Why not use `glob()` and filter out the ones you don't want? Maybe even DirectoryIterator.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, ummm, not trying to be rude, but right underneath my code, I say, "What I need to do now is turn all the files inside each directory into href links..."  Is that not specific enough???

Comment: Isn't adding an `<a>` tag making them all links? But you said you did that and it wasn't what you wanted. From seeing the answer below, I get that what you really wanted, you didn't want directories to be links, but only files. That is what you didn't say. And all I was asking for was a sample of your desired output which would have cleared this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function listFolderFiles($dir)
    {
        $ffs = scandir($dir);
        echo '<ol>';
        foreach($ffs as $ff)
        {
            if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..')
            {
                echo '<li>';
                if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff))
                {
                    echo $ff;
                    listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
                } else {
                    echo "<a href='$dir/$ff'>$ff</a>";
                }
                echo '</li>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ol>';
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, Sergio Mesquita.  This is EXACTLY what I was looking for.